# bootstrap_flash with ajax rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How should I get  bootstrap_flash working? 
this is my create.js.erb

```
$('.errors').html("<%= j render 'common/errors', resource:@answer %>");
$('.answers').append("<%= j render @answer %>");
$('.notice_flash'). ????????? I've tryed replaceWith(<%= bootstrap_flash%>)
```

this is standart slim from layout

```
 .container
  .row
    .col-lg-12
      .notice_flash                
        = bootstrap_flash
      = yield
```

and controller

```
def create    
@answer = @question.answers.new(answer_params)    
@answer.user = current_user       
flash.now[:notice] = "Successfully created" if @answer.save
```

end

Answer (score 0):

In `create.js.erb`:

`$('.notice_flash').html('<%= bootstrap_flash %>')`

Answer (score -1):

1. make a partial like views/shared/_notice.html.slim
2. in partial just write

   = bootstrap_flash
3. in yours create.js.erb

   ....
   $('.notice_flash').html("<%= j render 'share/noty' %>");
   ....